# React object.map not updating due to the key

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, reactjs

The basic problem I'm having is that I'm updating my data using an AJAX request and then setting the state of data, but in the view, the data never update even though my state is updated. I've figured out that it's because the key is the same (which it should be because I'm just using the ID mongoose provides).

If I do things like set the state to nothing and then set then set the new data then it updates. Or if I set the key to a randomly generated key it also works, but both of these don't feel right. I want to know what the correct way to re-render an updated object when using the map function.

It looks something like this:

```
Object.keys(this.state.data).map((i) => (
    <MyComponent key={ this.state.data[i]._id }
))
```

And then I have a basic AJAX request that does `this.setState({ data: response.data })`.

How do I make react update the data in the view for the updated item properly?

Answer (score 1):

Can you add the index as a prefix to the `_id`?

```
key={ `${i}_${this.state.data[i]._id}`}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure it is related to the key, if you console.log(this.state.data) just before your code it gets updated when it should? it seems to me that the props are not getting passed to the component.

I mean I often use the index of map in the key in the lists I never had any problem with that.